# Why does my shell script not accept arguments when run from PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, command-line-arguments

I have just compiled the source code for a program called [JohnTheRipper](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper). Currently, if I want to run `john` I have to `cd` into the `run/` directory and execute it with `./john`. However, I would much prefer being able to run the `john` command from any directory, as if it were installed system wide. I can't make an alias for this, because I need to be able to pass parameters to the binary. So I tried making a small shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/username/tools/JohnTheRipper/run/john $@
```

I placed this script into `/usr/local/bin` so that it is in my path. This script works, but **ONLY** if I run it by specifying the path.

```
$ ls john -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56 Mar 20 03:54 john
$ ./john --test
Will run 4 OpenMP threads
Benchmarking: descrypt, traditional crypt(3) [DES 256/256 AVX2-16]... (4xOMP)
...
```

It will not work if I try running it by using the `$PATH` environment variable

```
$ which john
/usr/local/bin/john
$ john --test
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `--test'
```

Why is this the case? Why aren't the command line arguments being passed to my shell script? And how can I set it up so that I can run the `john` command from any directory, allowing me to pass it arguments?

**Note** The solution must be able to accept relative paths when passing parameters to john. For example, if I am in the directory `d/` with a file `wordlist.txt` I want to be able to run john as such:

```
john --wordlist=./wordlist.txt
```

Comment: (1) What is the output of `type -a john`? (2) You should quote `$@` like this: `"$@"`. (3) `alias john='/home/username/tools/JohnTheRipper/run/john'` shouldn't interfere with arguments that follow `john` while invoking.

Comment: A better plan would be to symlink something in PATH to the path to john.

Answer (score 1):

The [comment by Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/questions/1415582/why-does-my-shell-script-not-accept-arguments-when-run-from-path?noredirect=1#comment2136983_1415582) helped me solve this issue. It was user error.

```
$ type -a john
john is aliased to `(cd ~/tools/JohnTheRipper/run/ && ./john )'
john is /usr/local/bin/john
```

In the above you can see the output of `type -a`. I originally created an alias that used a subscript, and when that didn't work I tried to symlink the executable, I tried different aliases, and I tried creating the aforementioned script. However, none of these worked because every time I made a change to `.bashrc` I ran

```
$ source .bashrc
```

I was unaware that `source` would not overwrite my original `john` alias... Since aliases take precedence over the `$PATH` variable, this whole time `john` was executing the same original subshell that wouldn't take arguments. By running `unalias john`, now everything works.

**NOTE** When it comes to making a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`, I agree this would be a better alternative, but unfortunately it does not work in this situation, as you can see from the following output:

```
$ ls -la john
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mar 20 12:31 john -> /home/username/tools/JohnTheRipper/run/john
$ john --test
fopen: $JOHN/john.conf: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You still have an error: `$@` should be `"$@"`. Without the quotes, you cannot pass in quoted or escaped arguments.